# Spring Integration and Spring Batch using Annotations [Spring-Batch-Integration]

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

Currently I am working on creating a POC for using Spring Integration and Spring Batch. I am following this [Spring Batch Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html). But i am trying to do this using annotation and Spring boot and dont want to use any XML configuration. Can anyone please suggest me how to user the JobLaunchingGateway from Spring Batch Integration. Please let me know if you need more details on same. Please find the below code sample which I am trying to get working.

```
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "outboundJobRequestChannel",replyChannel = "jobLaunchReplyChannel")
            public JobExecution jobLauncher(Message<JobLaunchRequest> jobLaunchRequestMessage){
                log.info("------ Inside the Gateway ------");
                JobExecution jobExecution = new JobExecution();

                // How to use the JobLaunchingGateway here in order to launch the job

                return jobExecution;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JobLaunchingGateway` is a `MessageHandler`. It should be used via `@ServiceActivator` annotation:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundJobRequestChannel", outputChannel = "jobLaunchReplyChannel")
public JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    return new JobLaunchingGateway(jobLauncher);
}
```

See the Spring Integration [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans).

Comment: I have tried this one but got the following exception,Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingGateway]:Circular reference involving containing bean 'integrationJobConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'jobLaunchingGateway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/MessageHandlingException

Comment: I am sure there are some version mismatch so i might have got this one.

Comment: That really sounds like version mismatch, indeed. Your answer isn't related. That's not how thing here in SO works...

Comment: First of all thanks for replying Artem, i agreed with you on that one, that why I haven't accepted the answer and I have just added the below snippet for reference. Once I resolve the version issue and try with the "JobLaunchingGateway" which is the right way, i will surly accept that one and close the post :).

Answer (score 0):

JobLaunchingMessageHandler worked for me, but i will also try to get it working using the JobLaunchingGateway as well.

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundJobRequestChannel", outputChannel = "nullChannel")
protected JobLaunchingMessageHandler jobLauncherHandler(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    log.info("-------------- Launching the JobLauncher Request --------------");
    return new JobLaunchingMessageHandler(jobLauncher);
}
```